# call onload from separate file

Tags: php, jquery

I have a file header.php which is being used by all other files. This file has body onload function. But this function is only being used by one other file called test.php. How can i call this function from test.php by using jQuery or php.

```
<body onLoad="setCountDown();">
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you the following:
- Remove the onload, so you'd have only `<body>`

- In your test.php put this:

  < script>
       $(setCountDown);
   < /script>

This way, the `setcountDown` only gets called when needed.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

In your header.php file, you'll want to change the line you provided to:

```
<body <?php 
    $currentFile = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
    $parts = explode('/', $currentFile);        // necessary?
    $currentFile = $parts[count($parts) - 1];   // necessary?

    if ($currentFile = 'test.php') echo "onload='setCountDown();'" ?>>
```

You'll want to test what the variable $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] resolves to, and you may not need the following two lines that I'm not sure are necessary.